# ASP.NET MVC autofill fields after dropdown selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4

Let's say I have 5 models (example to make stuff easy)

- ProductionOrderTBL {*PONo, LineItemNo*FK*, Date}
- SalesOrderTBL {*SONo, Customer, Date}
- LineItemTBL {*SONo,*LineItemNo, ProductCode, Quantity}
- ProductTBL {*ProductCode, ProductName, GroupID*FK*, UnitPrice}
- GroupTBL {*GroupID, GroupName}

I want to make a Production Order Form
- where the PONo. runs automatically
- where I can choose a Sales Order and LineItemNo through a cascade drop down list
- and in the end the ProductName, Quantity, UnitPrice and Group name should automatically fill in my my Production Order form and submit it.

I don't really get from all the tutorials how I connect all the tables together.
writing it in SQL would be

```
SELECT LineItemTBl.LineOrderNo, ProductTBL.ProductName
LineItemTBl.Quantity, ProductTBL.UnitPrice, GroupTBL.GroupName
FROM (LineItemTBL L INNER JOIN ProductTBL P ON L.ProductCode=P.ProductCode) INNER JOIN GROUPTBL G ON P.GroupID=G.GroupID
WHERE LineItemTBL.LineItemNo=... AND LineItemTBL.SONo=....;
```

**ProductionOrderController.cs**

```
    // GET: ProductionTBLs
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var productionTBLs = db.ProductionTBLs.Include(p => p.SalesOrderTBL).Include(p => p.SOLineItemTBL;
        return View(productionTBLs.ToList());
    }

    // GET: ProductionTBLs/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.SONo = new SelectList(db.SOTBLs, "SONo", "SONo");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: ProductionTBLs/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PONo, SoNo, LineItemNo, ProductName,Quantity, UnitPrice")] productionTBL ProductionTBL)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.ProductionTBLs.Add(productionTBL);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.SONo = new SelectList(db.SOTBLs, "SONo", "SONo", "productionTBL.SONo");
        ViewBag.LineItemNo = new SelectList(db.LineItemTBLs, "LineItemNo", "LineItemNo", "productionTBL.LineItemNo");
    }
```

**ProductionOrderCreate.cshtml**

```
@Html.DropDownList("SONo", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.DropDownList("LineItemNo", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductTBL.ProductName)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GroupTBL.GroupName)
```

Comment: what exactly your query is SQL to LINQ or Auto Fill Data on Dropdown selet?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee I don't understand what you mean

Comment: what do you want tell me

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee How do I do the coding?

Comment: coding for what that is what is the question